# Query conditionally return only one row per distinct id

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I am making a Reddit clone and I'm having trouble querying my list of posts, given a logged in user, that shows whether or not logged in user upvoted the post for every post. I made a small example to make things simpler.

I am trying to return only one row per distinct `post_id`, but prioritize the `upvoted` column to be `t > f > null`.

For this example data:

```
> select * from post;
 id
----
  1
  2
  3

> select * from users;
 id
----
  1
  2

> select * from upvoted;
 user_id | post_id
---------+---------
       1 |       1
       2 |       1
```

If I am given `user_id = 1` I want my query to return:

```
 postid | user_upvoted
--------+--------------
      1 | t
      2 | f
      3 | f
```

Since user1 upvoted post1, `upvoted` is `t`. Since user1 did not upvote post2, `upvoted` is `f`. Same for post3.

### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post (
    id              bigserial,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id              serial,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS upvoted (
    user_id         integer
        REFERENCES users(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    post_id         bigint
        REFERENCES post(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, post_id)
);
```

### What I tried so far

```
SELECT post.id as postid,
    CASE WHEN user_id=1 THEN true ELSE false END as user_upvoted
    FROM post LEFT OUTER JOIN upvoted
    ON post_id = post.id;
```

Which gives me:

```
 postid | user_upvoted
--------+--------------
      1 | t
      1 | f
      2 | f
      3 | f
```

Due to the join, there are two "duplicate" rows that result from the query. I want to priority the row with `t > f > null`. So I want to keep the `1 | t` row.

[Full script with schema+data.](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KzcKiPsk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `distinct on`:

```
SELECT distinct on (p.id) p.id as postid,
       (CASE WHEN user_id = 1 THEN true ELSE false END) as upvoted
FROM post p LEFT OUTER JOIN
     upvoted u
     ON u.post_id = p.id
ORDER BY p.id, upvoted desc;
```

Comment: Thank you! This was what I was looking for. My reddit clone finally works the way it should.

Just one concern - is the second `order by` in the end supposed to be there? I get a syntax error there, but when I do `ORDER BY p.id, upvoted desc;` it works fine.

Comment: @KeithYong . . . No, the second `order by` was not supposed to be there.

Comment: `DISTINCT ON` is expensive noise for this simple case. Nobody should use this. This would join to *every* upvote for every post, while we are only interested in the given user to begin with.

Comment: Because this answer gets periodic downvotes, I should point out that this solution does not assume that there is only one upvote per post.  Erwin's answer is also a fine answer, but it makes the assumption that there is only one upvote.

Answer (score 1):

The `exists()` operator yields a boolean value:

```
SELECT p.id
   , EXISTS (SELECT * FROM upvoted x
              WHERE x.post_id = p.id
                AND x.user_id = 1) AS it_was_upvoted_by_user1
FROM post p
        ;
```

Comment: Better than `DISTINCT ON` here, but you forgot `AND x.user_id = 1`.

Comment: Okay, I see... edit ... On thecond thought not: `I am trying to return only one row per distinct post_id`

Comment: Yes, per distinct `post_id`, my comment still applies. Your current query returns whether the post has *any* upvotes, but the OP is interested whether it has an upvote from the given user: `whether or not logged in user upvoted the post`.

Comment: My brain started working again, finally. You were right. of course.

Answer (score 1):

Since the combination `(user_id, post_id)` is defined unique in `upvoted` (`PRIMARY KEY`), this can be **much simpler**:

```
SELECT p.id AS post_id, u.post_id IS NOT NULL AS user_upvoted
FROM   post p
LEFT   JOIN upvoted u ON u.post_id = p.id
                     AND u.user_id = 1;
```

Simply add  `user_id = 1` to the join condition. Makes perfect use of the index and should be simplest and fastest.

You also mention NULL, but there are only two distinct states in the result: `true` / `false`.

#### Alternative approach

On second thought, you might be complicating a very basic task. If you are only interested in posts the current user upvoted, use this **simple query** instead:

```
SELECT post_id FROM upvoted WHERE user_id = 1;
```

All other posts are not upvoted by the given user. It would seem we don't have to list those explicitly.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2cf3b/3)